# How do I write to mongodb?

Tags: mongoid

I am trying to write a query as follows:

```
ecg = Ecg.create(:collection, options: { timestamp: Time.now,, voltage: 
-1.3, metadata: { user_id: 1}})
```

My Ecg model is as follows:

```
class Ecg
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :voltage, type: Float
  field :timestamp, type: Time
  belongs_to :user


  store_in collection_options: {
    time_series: {
      timeField: "timestamp",
      metaField: "metadata",
      granularity: "milliseconds"
    }
  }
end
```

The error is vague to me it says the pattern does not match.

The error is as follows:
message:
Invalid options passed to Ecg.store_in: {:collection_options=>{:time_series=>{:timeField=>"timestamp", :metaField=>"metadata", :granularity=>"milliseconds"}}}.
summary:
The :store_in macro takes only a hash of parameters with the keys :database, :collection, or :client.
resolution:
Change the options passed to store_in to match the documented API, and ensure all keys in the options hash are symbols.

Example:
  class Band
    include Mongoid::Document
    store_in collection: 'artists', database: 'music'
  end

Comment: I am using the latest version of mongoid

Answer (score 0):

The API for working with timeseries collections was added to Mongoid in [8.1.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid/versions/8.1.0) ([MONGOID-5370](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-5370)).

If you're using an older version of Mongoid this error would likely be raised. Can you verify you're using at least 8.1.0?